# Jquery cannot get id from django generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am trying to retrieve an elements ID on click. The element is a div generated by django:

```
        {% for artist in artists %}
        <div class="band_box_inner" id='artist_{{artist.id}}' style="background-image: url({{artist.pic_primary.url}})">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

The element is correctly displayed on the page. I am trying to retrieve the elements ID when it is clicked:

```
$('html').on('click', '.band_box_container', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

However, every time this function alerts "undefined".

When I use:

```
$('html').on('click', '.band_box_container', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

I correctly get the html of the element, including the id.

Why is my jquery selector not picking up the django generated template tag elements.attributes?

Comment: Can you try `$(this).id`?

Comment: Still returns undefined. What is really odd, is if I add the on click listener to a wrapping parent element, and then use $(this).find('.band_box_inner').first().atr('id') it works as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Ids do not match.
band_box_inner vers band_box_container